# Cant find element in IIS 7.5 Configuration Editor

Tags: iis-7.5

I just learned about this wonderful tool, but I cant seem to figure out how to use it.

For Application (under App Pools), Advanced Settings, there is an Idle Time-out setting, I cant figure out how or where to find it in Config Editor

In XML export obtained via: `appcmd list apps /xml /app.name:"myApp/" /config:* > text.txt` 
it is located in Appcmd\AppPool\add\ProcessModel

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the following should work :

> appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/webLimits
>   /dynamicIdleThreshold:"150" /commit:apphost

Comment: Hi, it doesnt look like I have system.applicationhost in my Config Editor.  Would you mind explaining how you go about matching a particular property to location in Config Editor?

I have a fair number of properties that I have to modify and I would like to learn to how locate them my self.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have it, you just need to start Config Editor from the Server level, not a website level.

The Server level is where system.applicationHost is effective, so it's only visible from there too. Also, you'll need to ensure you're targeting applicationhost.config, not a web.config file, for the same reason.